# Extracting xml values using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have my xml file which has below data

```
<User text="HHd5">
         <max string="0"/>
         <min string="pick up"/>
         <valat string="0"/>
         <valon string="0"/>
         <time string="GMT"/>     
 </User>
```

through my script, i need to check for User text ie. HHd5. If found, i must extract valat and valon values. Please help

My code:

```
$file = "text.xml" 
$xml = new XML::Simple( KeyAttr => [] );
$data = $xml->XMLin("$file");
my $booklist = XMLin('$file');
foreach my $var ( @{ $booklist->{ User text } } ) {
    if ( $var->{ User text } eq "HHd5" ) { $var->{valat}; $var->{valon}; }
```

And:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open( fp, "<", "testing.xml" );
$s = "HHd5";
while (<fp>) {
    $a = $_;
    if ( $a =~ /$s/ ) {
        while (<fp>) {
            $f = $_;
            if ( $f =~ /valon string="(\d+)/ ) { print "valon $1 \n"; }
            if ( $f =~ /valat string="(\d+)/ ) { print "valat $1 \n"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get better responses if you can show what you've tried so far, and explain what problems you're having. Otherwise this looks a bit like a homework question, so may well attract less constructive responses.

Comment: can we achieve this using xml simple.. i am new to scripting. Please help

Comment: $file="text.xml"
$xml = new XML::Simple (KeyAttr=>[]);
$data = $xml->XMLin("$file");
my $booklist = XMLin('$file');   



foreach my $var (@{$booklist->{User text}}) {
if($var->{User text} eq "HHd5"){
                $var->{valat};
                $var->{valon};
}

Comment: Look at the doc for `XML::Simple` : http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#STATUS_OF_THIS_MODULE Specifically: "The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. "

Comment: Can I suggest reformatting that code and editing your post. As it stands, it doesn't work. I don't want to amend it because that might change the context of the question.

Comment: Also - your XML appears incomplete. I assume you've just cut out the piece you're interested in - a bit more context would make it easier to assemble a solution.

Comment: i tried this.   it is giving me proper value. But please improvize my code

Comment: #! /usr/bin/perl
open(fp,"<","testing.xml");

$s="BSC01_site";
while(<fp>){

$a=$_;
        if($a =~ /$s/){
                while(<fp>){
                        $f=$_;
                        if( $f =~ /valon string="(\d+)/){
                                print "valon $1 \n";
                        }
      if( $f =~ /valat string="(\d+)/){
                                print "valat $1 \n";
                        }
                }
        }
}

Comment: Editing your question rather than commenting is the way forward. That code snippet looks like you're nesting `while` loops, which would be unwise.

Comment: And you're not closing your quotes. Which is also not going to work.

Answer (score 4):

Using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for //User[@text='HHd5']
    echo valat/@string valon/@string ;
```

Or, a more verbose solution using [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) only:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml( location => 'file.xml' );
for my $user ($xml->documentElement->findnodes('//User[@text="HHd5"]')) {
    print $_->{string},"\n" for $user->findnodes('valat | valon');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me start with a personal peeve. XML is a strict language spec, and it has formal definitions as to what is - and isn't - allowed. Therefore it's actually very easy to parse with a parser, and gets horribly messy if you try and use a hand rolled solution like a regular expression.

Not least because XML can have linefeeds and be reformatted and still be valid.

I would also suggest - don't use `XML::Simple`. In it's module page:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

Also - it's really important that you start a script with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These are really good ways to help diagnose problems and will also get much better responses if you're posting code on Stack Overflow.

With that in mind, I'd suggest picking up `XML::Twig` which has the ability to set `twig_handlers` - subroutines that are triggered to process a specific chunk of XML. In the example below - I specify `twig_roots` which indicates to the parser that I don't really care about anything else.

`process_user` is called with each `User` element. We test the `User` element for it having the appropriate attribute - and if it does, we extract the string attributes from the two subelements you're interested in.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub process_user {
    my ( $twig, $user ) = @_;
    if ( $user->att('text') eq "HHd5" ) {
        print $user->first_child('valat')->att('string'), ":",
            $user->first_child('valon')->att('string');
    }
}

my $parser = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'User' => \&process_user, } );
$parser->parse( \*DATA );

__DATA__
<User text="HHd5">
         <max string="0"/>
         <min string="pick up"/>
         <valat string="0"/>
         <valon string="0"/>
         <time string="GMT"/>     
 </User>
```

But simplifying a bit perhaps, to make it similar to your existing code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml_twig = XML::Twig->new();
$xml_twig->parsefile("test.xml");

foreach my $user ( $xml_twig->root->children('User') ) {
    if ( $user->att('text') eq "HHd5" ) {
        print $user ->first_child('valat')->att('string');
        print ":";
        print $user ->first_child('valon')->att('string');
    }
}
```

(NB: The example above doesn't quite work with your XML snippet, but that's because I'm assuming that `User` isn't your root node in your XML. It couldn't be really. )

Answer (score -1):

to deal with parsing XML, the best way is to download a module from CPAN like XML::Simple. it will be worth your time to get this module, or one like it, and learn how to use it, if you are going to work with XML. these modules basically convert XML into a complex Perl variable (hash reference). manually parsing XML is not advised on a large scale.

however, in the case of a quick ad-hoc situation, you could parse it with regex.

```
open(my $xml,"<","file.xml");

my ($user, $valat, $valon);
while (my $line = <$xml>) {
    # regexes to capture your variables
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree on both points - `XML::Simple` is nasty. And so is parsing XML with regular expressions.

Comment: i've implied both of those things in my answer, but remember that by all appearances, OP is a beginner. for beginners, sometimes what is the easy way to us is the hard way for them.

Comment: That's the problem though - XML parsing via regex _isn't_ the easy way. It may look like it, but it's "easy" in exactly the same way of turning off `strict` and `warnings` makes errors go away. It may well work, but it's also extremely prone to creating brittle code and exploding messily later. I wouldn't suggest to _anyone_ that they do either of these things, but especially a beginner - an expert may well know better.

Comment: fair enough. one could abstract OP's question out to "what's the best way to parse xml?". then again maybe it's just "what's the easiest way to extract 3 strings from some text?" :)